# jquery to prevent duplicate elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a jquery code.

There are a ul  and li

my code is following

```
      var responses = response;

        for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {

            if ($("#" + $("#sp").val()).attr("class") == "more") {
                // alert("if");

                $("#p_li").append("<ul class='fwd'><li><a href='#' onclick='cs1(this)'>" + responses[i] + "</a></li></ul>").before();

            }

    }
```

I want parent li, that's: "$("#p_li")" not to have duplicate elements(thats li with same string text). Keep in mind that p_li contains data before this function runs

the responses contains list of cities.

I have tried this condition but it's failing

```
if ($('#fwd > li:contains(' + responses[i] + ')').length == 0)
```

Comment: I don't see any `id` attr with name of `fwd`. It should be `.fwd` Correct it.

Comment: it fixed the problem but some other problem pops up

Answer (score 0):

There is function ***[.unique()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/)*** in jQuery. If you give it an array having duplicate values it'll return you a new array that will have unique values.

If the *responses* array contains all the cities names with duplicate values, you should first remove the duplicates with *.unique()* and then with the new unique array create your elements.

Comment: the responses array returns unique values. But p_li has some values from before

Comment: So, you want to add responses and p_li and remove duplicates from the combined array?

Comment: If so then first add both of your arrays (responses and p_li) and then use .unique() to remove the duplicates and after that create your desired element with unique values.

Comment: actually p_li is a <li> that contains elements